# How to get error from custom function which calls orginal function? do you have better suggestion?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, error-handling

How to get error from custom function which calls orginal function?
Do you have better suggestion?

**Custom TCreateFile function**
this TCreateFile function calls orginal CreateFile function.

```
 void* tCreateFile(const char* pFileName,
                  unsigned long dwDesiredAccess, 
                  unsigned long dwShareMode, 
                  unsigned long dwCreationDisp,
                  unsigned long dwFlagsAndAttr) // short version of CreateFile
{
           void* hnd = ::CreateFile(pFileName, 
                               dwDesiredAccess,
                               dwShareMode, 
                               NULL,
                               dwCreationDisp,
                               dwFlagsAndAttr, 
                               NULL); // real version of createfile

if(hnd == (void*)-1) ::SetLastError(::GetLastError());

return hnd;
}
```

**Some function**
this function checks if error exist ,if not run code

```
char* Function()
{

void* hfile = tCreateFile("C:\\Test.txt", 
                         (GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_READ),
                         (FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE),
                         OPEN_EXISTING, 
                         FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL);

if(hfile != (void*)-1) 
{
 code....
}
else
{
 return GetErrorMessage(::GetLastError());
}
}
```

**GetErrorMessage function**
if some function fails GetErrorMessage function returns error string

```
char* GetErrorMessage(unsigned long IsError)
{
 switch(IsError)
   {
   case 2L: // ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
   {
   return "Warning: file not found!\n\nPlease check if the file exists and try again.";
   break;
   }
   case 32L: // ERROR_FILE_IN_USE
   {
   return "Warning: file in use!\n\nPlease close all applications that use the file.";
   break;
   }
   .....
   .....
   .....
  default:
   {
   return "Warning: unknown error!";
   break;
   }
  }
 }
```

Comment: What do you want to do with the follwing :`if(hnd == (void*)-1) ::SetLastError(::GetLastError());` ?

Comment: im call custom function short version of orginal Createfile and than custom function calls orginal CreateFile function and if hnd == 0xffffffff or (void*)-1 i use SetLastError() to save GetLastError() value.. without SetLastError() inside Custom function , GetLastError() will be 0xfffffff.. but if you call orginal CreateFile function without custom createfile function its enough to call GetLastError()

Comment: Why `GetLastError` should change when you return from your modified function? Sounds suspicious.

Comment: this is becoz that custom TCreateFile function return handle form orginal CreateFile function so it get like this orginal function return handle and custom function returns same handle if you will call GetLastError() after custom function returns handle u will get 0xfffffff(we are talking about error now) so 0xfffffff is invalid handle..but not 2L or 32L. but you can choose how to get right error orginal&simple CreateFile->GetLastError() or this not perfect but amazing function TCreateFile->CreateFile->SetLastError(GetLastError())->GetLastError() something like that

Comment: Understand this: CreateFile calls SetLastError, and sets the global (thread specific) DWORD variable, which is returned by GetLastError. You need NOT to call it at all.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the void* is because you don't know what type of error response the original function will return.

Void pointers aren't type safe, though, and you can't dynamic_cast<> a void* either. This looks like it could lead to some memory corruptions.

Best bet would probably be to create a partial specialization Error wrapper class, and implement the different return types there, then return this Error wrapper from your method.

Comment: Not true. 

#define DECLARE_HANDLE(name) struct name##__{int unused;}; typedef struct name##__ *name